# Парадокс двойного клика по приложения win32

Tags: c, консоль, окно

Вопрос в общем то уже кажется мне маловажным но всё же любопытным. Сегодня установил что файл приложения win32 (написанный на С с оператором getchar(); в конце) открывается двойным кликом и остаётся открытым если он находится вне папки проекта, отдельно от других файлов созданных Pelles C IDE
Если же исполняемый файл находится внутри папки с остальными файлами проекта, то останется он открытым после двойного клика или же мигнёт и тут же свернётся зависит от положения окна папки на мониторе. Если окно папки проекта сдвинуто вниз или вправо, то консольное окно остаётся открытым. Если сдвинуто вверх и не находится в правой части монитора то мигает и сворачивается. Если окно папки развёрнуто на весь экран то всегда мигает и сворачивается. В общем вот поясняющее полутораминутное видео https://youtu.be/3o7TJjQa1hA

Comment: Что-то у меня подозрение, что это связано с вашими настройками Windows, но уж никакого отношения к C этот вопрос не имеет...

Comment: 1. Проверьте поведение exe на другой системе. Вполне вероятно, что это баг/особенность вашей Windows. 2. Скомпилируйте программу другим компилятором (MinGW-w64), т.к. есть вероятность, что это баг/особенность используемого в Pelles C компилятора.